# FIFO: Output is at meta-stable state before sending next byte

Tags: verilog, fifo

**Objective:** Implement a 15 Byte FIFO with Parallel-in -> Serial Out.

**Expected Outcome(s):**

- receive 8 bits of data on positive edge of data_available signal
- once 15bytes received

  - send each byte(bit-by-bit) sequentially on output until all data sent
- while transmitting to data_out, new data can come in

  - if new data available, store it

FIFO Module:

```
//`timescale 1 ns / 100 ps
module fifo(rd_clk, data_out, data_in, rst, data_available);
    // input & output ports
    output data_out; // 1b serial out
    input [7:0] data_in; // 8b parallel in
    input rd_clk;
    input rst;
    input data_available;

    // registers
    reg [3:0] cs, rp, wp; // 4b(max=15)
    reg data_out;

    // internal only
    reg data_out_ready;
    reg [7:0] data_ram[0:14]; // Buffer 15 x 8bit

    // common reset
    always @(posedge rd_clk or posedge rst)
    begin:Reset
        if(rst) begin
            wp <= 4'b0;
            rp <= 4'b0;
            cs <= 4'b0;
            data_out <= 1'b0;
            data_out_ready <= 1'b0;
        end
    end


    always @(posedge data_available)
    begin:Writing

        if(!eql_addr) begin
            data_ram[wp] = data_in;
            #1 wp <= wp + 4'b0001;

            if(wp == 14) begin
                #1 data_out_ready <= 1'b1;
                #1 wp <= 4'b0;
            end
        end

    end

    always @(posedge rd_clk)
    begin:Reading

        if(data_out_ready)
        begin
            data_out = data_ram[cs][rp];
            rp <= rp + 4'b0001;

            if(rp == 4'b1000) begin
                cs <= cs + 4'b0001;
                rp <= 4'b0;
            end

            if(cs == 15) begin
                cs <= 4'b0;
                data_out_ready <= 1'b0;
            end
        end
        else
            data_out <= 0;

    end

    assign eql_addr = (cs == wp) && data_out_ready;

endmodule
```

Following is my test bench module

```
// `timescale 1 ns / 1 ps
module fifo_tb;

    reg rst, clk, wr_en;
    wire data_out;
    reg [7:0] data_in;

    // waveform dump for gtkwave
    initial
        begin
            $dumpfile("fifo.vcd");
        $dumpvars(0,fifo_tb);
    end

    fifo f1 (clk, data_out, data_in, rst, wr_en);

    initial
        begin
        wr_en <= 0;
        rst <= 1;
        clk <= 0;
        data_in <= 8'b0;
    end

    always #100 clk =~ clk; // flip clock every 100time-units

    initial
        begin
        #100 rst = 1'b1;
        #100 rst = 1'b0;
        #100 data_in = 8'b01010110;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b0;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b1;
        #100 data_in = 8'b11001101;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b0;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b1;
        #100 data_in = 8'b11011100;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b0;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b1;
        #100 data_in = 8'b00110011;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b0;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b1;
        #100 data_in = 8'b00111100;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b0;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b1;
        #100 data_in = 8'b11001100;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b0;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b1;
        #100 data_in = 8'b00111100;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b0;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b1;
        #100 data_in = 8'b10110011;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b0;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b1;
        #100 data_in = 8'b11111111;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b0;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b1;
        #100 data_in = 8'b00001111;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b0;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b1;
        #100 data_in = 8'b00111010;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b0;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b1;
        #100 data_in = 8'b01100110;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b0;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b1;
        #100 data_in = 8'b00110000;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b0;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b1;
        #100 data_in = 8'b01100010;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b0;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b1;
        #100 data_in = 8'b11000001;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b0;
        #10 wr_en = 1'b1;
        #50000 ; // wait
        $finish;
    end

endmodule
```

Here is the waveform study:
[image: Waveform Study of FIFO module]

**Problems:**

- data_out_ready is never enabled if wp is compared to 15, only to 14
- at the serial output, after every byte is sent, a meta-stable(x) state is emitted until next byte is sent

I am trying to figure out why this meta-stable state is introduced after every byte(at data_out) and I also noticed that the data_out is fine but is shifted by 1 bit, i.e. the bit for 0th position(rp = 0) is shown at 1st position(rp = 1) when reading.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rp was incrementing unto 8 , as the array element( were upto 7)  reading data_ram[n][8] was generating x. This also could also be why bits were getting shifted.
Also the cs comparison can be updated to generate all 15 bytes.

Two changes  in - begin:Reading

```
        if(rp == 4'b0111) begin

        if(cs == 14 && rp == 4'b0111) begin
```

You may not want to use #delay in your code. 
Is the write interface an asynchronous interface ?

Comment: If you mean the Write block, yes, it should only accept data when I have a positive edge at `data_available`.

Comment: Thanks! It's working now perfectly. I think yes, the data_ram[n][8] was generating the meta-stable state. Now everything is synchronized again.

Comment: sounds good , but is that external block also based on a clock ? do you want to also get a write clock into the block ?

Comment: Thanks again! No, write is async. The `data_out` clock is ~77 times faster than `data_available` pulses, so the design specification wants me to use the positive edge of `data_available` only, no clocks allowed.